# Using Maybe helpers with If statement Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
module Meth where


put :: (Int,Int) -> [(Int,Int)]
put (a,b) = [(a,b)]

checker :: [(Int,Int)] -> Int
checker b = snd(last(b))

swap :: [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)]
swap [(a,b)] = [(b,a)]
```

I want to concatenate a pair into a list of pairs if the pair matches with the second last element in the list of pairs. I am using a Maybe type and it is throwing an error which is really long to post. any help would be appreciated thanks

```
qwerty :: (Int,Int)-> [(Int,Int)] -> Maybe [(Int,Int)]
qwerty (a,c) b = if snd(last b) == fst(head (put (a,c))) then Just b ++ put((a,c)) else 
                                                                         if snd(last b) ==  snd(head (put (a,c))) then Just b ++ swap (put(a,c)) else Nothing
```

Comment: I hope you realise that `snd(last(b))` doesn't get you "the second last element in a list of pairs", but rather "the second element of the last pair in a list of pairs"? e.g. in `[(1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33)]` the second last pair would be `(2, 22)`, but what `snd(last(b))` would actually extract is `33`.

Comment: yeah that's what I was going for. but thanks anyway

Comment: Cool, just checking that wasn't related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Just b ++ put((a,c))` is parsed as `(Just b) ++ put((a,c))`, which is invalid.  It appears you should write `Just ( b ++ put((a,c)) )` instead, and likewise for `Just ( b ++ swap (put(a,c)) )`.